# SWIG generated java code not handling exceptions on 64 bit Solaris

Tags: java, c++, solaris, swig

I am using swig to generate java code from c++. The c++ code throws exceptions. They are caught fine on Windows, both in 32 bit and 64 bit code. It also works fine on Solaris for 32 bit. However on 64 bit Solaris, any exception coming out of the c++ code is not caught in a Java program.

This is the relevant part of call stack produced by java. Here CheckThrowError is the function in the c++ library throwing the exception.

```
tack: [0xfffffd7ffd34f000,0xfffffd7ffd44f000],  sp=0xfffffd7ffd44e4f8,  free space=1021k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  0x00000000000ad7c5
C  [libc.so.1+0xe18a9]  _Unwind_RaiseException+0x46
C  [libstdc++.so.6.0.3+0xdc74e]  __cxa_throw+0x5e
C  [libcsclientswig.so+0x552e9]  CheckThrowError(ATLAS::blob_status)+0x37
```

I am using gcc 3.4.3. Here CheckThrowError is the function in the library that is throwing the exception.

I would really appreciate any guidance in trying to troubleshoot this issue.

Comment: What are your gcc arguments?  Try using `-Wall -Wextra` to see if you can find something like a 64-to-32-bit error.

Comment: Thanks, Andrew. I found the issue and I have replied below.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, in case anyone else runs into it. Essentially, exception handling differs between Solaric C runtime used by Java from the GCC runtime used to build the c++ library, resulting in a failure to catch the exception. The hack to fix it involves forcing the GCC runtime to be loaded first, resulting in proper exception handling. I did it using the LD_PRELOAD environment variable.

```
    export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/sfw/lib/amd64/libgcc_s.so
```

After this, the Java code is able to handle the exception originating in c++. Why this was not a problem with 32 bit, I do not know.

Comment: That's nasty.  I'd think that means that exception handling in the Solaris runtime is now broken.  If you have an Oracle support contract, I'd open an issue over this.  They may not be able to fix it as GCC and "standard" Solaris exception handling may be fundamentally incompatible, but you won't know if you don't try.